# Pro-tem moderators? Is it time to start nominations yet?

Tags: discussion, beta, moderation

How old do we have to be to start nominating pro-tem nominators? I see we haven't got anyone to 2,000 yet but I have a few people I'd like to nominate.

Should we do it now? Wait till we've got several people above 2000 or wait for some other event?

Comment: I think we should wait.

Comment: @VMAtm: A couple of weeks or a couple of 2K's or?

Comment: If we can get a few people to 2K, then we can probably do quite a bit ourselves. The SE employees seem to be doing a good job for us, I vote we try to get them to do all the work for us for as long as we can ;-)

Comment: @hippietrail a couple of 2K's

Comment: +2K rep users have nothing to do with the pro tem program or having effective moderators. The advice in these comments is ill advised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! You should already be having (have had?) these discussions.

> #### Make Sure Your Community is Well Represented
>
> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice.

Please read:

[**The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

[**Moderator Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

We have not yet appointed the temporary moderators to this site, but you are already [well past the 14-day mark](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel).

Comment: Well despite our reservations and since those up above tell us we're slow, here is the topic for nominations. Please go nominate etc: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/160/pro-tem-moderator-nominations