# Pro-tem moderator nominations.

Tags: discussion, beta, moderation

While [we didn't think we were ready, those in charge tell us we are late to begin](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158/pro-tem-moderators-is-it-time-to-start-nominations-yet) nominating pro-tem moderators. So here is the place to nominate.

In each answer nominate exactly one person and give some brief reasons why. Multiple answers for multiple nominations are find and encouraged.

To support a nomination vote it up.

To disapprove of a nomination vote it down. As with all downvoting an explanation is encouraged but not enforced.

It's OK to nominate yourself.

**EDIT**

I forgot one important thing! For those nominated, please feel free to:

- accept the nomination in a comment
- decline the nomination in a comment
- mull it over for a while and comment that you're doing so
- mull it over for a while and then mull over if and when to comment on your intention to accept or decline (-;
- **read the appropriate SE pages on what it means to be a pro-tem moderator**: see *[Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)* and [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Comment: I want to throw in a comment, that we should be looking at people who are active in meta (although, active in meta generally equals active on site).

Comment: Thanks Dori, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 10):

[Ankur Banerjee](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/108/ankur-banerjee)

Seems to be putting in the most effort to cover every aspect of travel.SE and either knows about or is resourceful enough to find answers about lots of unexpected corners of the globe, which has brought him near the top of our users at this point.

Comment: Thanks, I try my best. :)

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee Grats witj 2000!

Comment: @VMAtm: Thanks. Nice to join your club! :)

Answer (score 7):

[Mark Mayo](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo)

He seems to be a hardcore traveller that goes to places not everyone goes (long tail), supplies a steady stream of good questions and good answers, and this has brought him near the top of our users currently.

Comment: @Mark Mayo Grats with 2000!

Comment: well that was fast and well spotted, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

[VMAtm](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19/vmatm)

Seems to be able to find answers to questions I expect nobody knows the answers to. And keeps doing it. Seems to take above average interest in the site and put in above average effort. This has brought him toward the top of our users so far.

Comment: Definitely second this - my goodness some of the quality of his answers about Russia and the 'stans have been fantastically useful, and quick too!

Comment: +1 Good answers and active.

Comment: I'll do my best, thank you. This is great honor for me.

Answer (score 4):

[hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail)

hippietrail has taken active steps in defining the direction of Travel.SE community during its initial stages, through discussions on Meta and by initiating discussions on what questions should be a fit for this site or not. He is [the most active editor so far](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all), doing a lot of the clean-up and re-tagging that makes this site usable. He has asked/answered questions related to alternative modes of travelling. He also often leaves behind comments that provide valuable information / personal experience, which doesn't earn him reputation but does add value to many existing answers.

Comment: Haha thanks Ankur but I'm sure I'm quite controversial here too (-:

Comment: @hippietrail: That's what the voting is for! :)

Comment: I'm right - the only one with a downvote so far d-:

Answer (score 2):

[Gagravarr](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26/gagravarr)

Gagravarr has gained 2000+ reputation so I guess he already has access to moderator tools but it's a measure how well he has answered a wide range of questions on Travel.SE. While most of the other contributors seem to be backpackers and can answer those questions easily, Gagravarr has given answers to questions that would be of value to business travellers too, helping Travel.SE be relevant to a different kind of audience too.

One could almost forgive him for getting the spelling of beloved (?) H2G2 character **[Gargravarr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_characters#Gargravarr)** wrong. ;) Or maybe he's Gargravarr's twin from another dimension, who chooses to spell his name differently. His deep, ethereal disembodied voice guides many a lost traveller with sane advice.