# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: vmatm]
[image: mark-mayo]
[image: ankur-banerjee]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several months.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

**N.B.** Thanks to everyone who participated in the [Pro-tem moderator nominations](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/pro-tem-moderator-nominations?answertab=votes) discussion. It shouldn't be a surprise to anyone that the top three vote-getters there are the ones being announced here!

Comment: I'm honoured to be chosen for this position and the people who supported me in the discussion. Here's to making Travel.SE an interesting community to hang out in!

Comment: @pnuts [status-completed] is typically used for feature requests, bug fixes, or other requests. This post is informational, so it doesn't need that tag :)

Comment: @pnuts If it makes easier to filter, done :)