# 2013 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

Travel Stack Exchange's [first ever moderator election](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Ankur Banerjee]
[image: mindcorrosive]
[image: RoflcopterException]

That's two new faces joining Ankur Banerjee — please thank them all for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with the new folks while they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/1042122/0).

And of course, a big thank you to the other [moderators pro tempore](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) who will now be stepping down for all their hard work up until this point:

[image: mark mayo]
[image: VMAtm]

Congratulations all around!

Comment: Congratulations to all! Well deserved results.

Comment: Congrats to the two new moderators, feels quite strange to not see the menu when I log in, but it'll be nice to see someone else deal with the fun times that comes with the position ;)

Comment: Thanks for everyone who voted for me - and everyone else in the election, regardless of whether they won or not! :)